# How do I get yesterday's date with customized time?

Tags: c#

I want to get yesterday's `date` with the `time` of my choice ( customized time ) and store it in a variable in windows forms C#.

For example: if today's `date/Time` was `2010-09-25 10:05:03` I want to get the `date` of the previous day ( `2010-09-24` ) and change the `time` to `14:30:00` then store it in a variable.

The following codes might help:

```
DateTime.Now; // it gives you today's Date and current Time 

DateTime.Today.AddHours(14:5); // it gives you the current date with customized time (`14:30:00`).

DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1); // it gives you the previous day
```

Please help me how to achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried combining the statements? `DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).AddHours(14.5)`

Comment: `DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).AddHours(14.5)`

Comment: yes it worked ,thank you

Comment: But I do not know why I got -4 down vote????????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the statements like this

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date.AddHours(14.5);
```

But remember DateTime objects are immutable so every time you modify a DateTime object you have to assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `DateTime.Now.Date` to cut time off, and then add time components.

```
var result = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1)
    .AddHours(14)
    .AddMinutes(30)
    .AddSeconds(21);
```

It will result in `14:30:21` of the previous day.